# Add uniqueness to element value in XSD

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, wsdl, xsd-validation

I need some help in XSD,I want to make itemName as unique,that is you cannot specify 2 items with same name. I tried below xsd for this XML.Please let me know where i went wrong. Below xml is validating with XSD but it should return error.

```
<records>
  <name>John</name>
  <items>
    <itemName>Dryer</itemName>
    <itemPrice>20</itemPrice>
  </items>
  <items>
    <itemName>Dryer</itemName>
    <itemPrice>20</itemPrice>
  </items>
</records>
```

XSD:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="records">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
        <xs:element name="items" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="itemName"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:int" name="itemPrice"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="uniqueItemName">
      <xs:selector xpath="itemName"/>
      <xs:field xpath="."/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. You just need to adjust the XPath for the `xs:selector` to match `items/itemName` relative from the `records` element that the `xs:unique` is defined:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="records">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                <xs:element name="items" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="itemName"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:int" name="itemPrice"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="uniqueItemName">
            <xs:selector xpath="items/itemName"/>
            <xs:field xpath="."/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```